# Java : iterate list of list in java

Tags: java, list, iterator

I wondering how the iterator works :

```
List<List<Integer>> res;
for (List l : res) {
}

for (Integer a : res) {
}
```

which one is right?  I am very confusing....

Comment: Well, which one of those two options _doesn't_ give you a compile error?

Comment: I got it, second one is wrong.@DavidWallace Thank you

Comment: OK, but do you understand why?

Comment: because iterator only goes through every element of res, in this case, element is list not integer. Am I right? @DavidWallace

Comment: Yeah, that'll do.  You should also really specify the type parameter whenever you use a `List` - this allows the compiler to check that you're putting the right kinds of things into the `List`, and taking the right kinds of things out.  Look at @Eran's answer for the right way to do that.

Answer (score 3):

You have a list of lists, so you need a nested loop if you wish to iterate over all the integers of all the inner lists :

```
for (List<Integer> l : res) {
    for (Integer a : l) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use iterators you can do as following

```
    Iterator<List<Integer>> itr = res.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        Iterator<Integer> itr1 = itr.next().iterator();
        while(itr1.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(itr1.next());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use streams and then flat map to integers to iterate over all the integers. For example to find the sum of all integers:

```
res.stream().flatMapToInt(List::stream).sum();
```

It's worth learning streams over for loops.

Comment: what is advantage of using stream?

Comment: There are plenty of advantages to streams. They (arguably) make the meaning clearer: take a stream of lists, map to a stream of integers inside the list, sum the integers. They also allow you to take advantage of multi-processors by switching to parallel streams without changing any of your logic.